# Merging pandas dataframe while replacing values and np.nans?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I have an old dataset that's been updated with new observations and new fields. I would like to consolidate the two but I have some discrepancies between the two datasets.

As you can see, ids 1 & 2 have values of 0 in the new dataset, but I would like to have the old values overwrite this

```
df_old = id   value   color              df_new = id   value   color   size
          1     100     b                          1     0       b      4
          2     100     b                          2     0       b      4  
          3     100     b                          3    100      b      4
          4     100     b                          4    100      b      4
          5     100     b                          7    100      b      4
          6     100     b                          8    100      b      4
```

I would like the final output to look something like

```
df_success  = id   value   color   size
               1    100      b      4
               2    100      b      4
               3    100      b      4
               4    100      b      4
               5    100      b      np.nan
               6    100      b      np.nan
               7    100      b      4
               8    100      b      4
```

My attempt involves an outer merge on id, and feeding a lambda a custom function to replace 0s and nans

```
df_trial = pd.merge(df_old, df_new, how='outer', on='id')

df_trial = id  value_x   color_x    value_y   color_y   size
            1   100        b          0         b         4
            2   100        b          0         b         4
            3   100        b         100        b         4
            4   100        b         100        b         4
            5   100        b         np.nan     np.nan    np.nan
            6   100        b         np.nan     np.nan    np.nan
            7   np.nan     np.nan    100        b         4 
            8   np.nan     np.nan    100        b         4
```

I would run

```
def get_values(values_x, values_y):
    if values_y == 0 or values_y == np.nan
        return values_x
    else:
        return values_y

df_hopeful['value_xy'] = df_trial.apply(lambda x:get_values(x['value_x'], x['value_y']), axis=1)

#and similarly for the color column to get rid of NaNs I will do this with an identical function #called 'get_color'

df_hopeful == id  value_x   color_x    value_y   color_y   size     value_xy   color_xy
               1   100        b          0         b         4         100        b
               2   100        b          0         b         4         100        b
               3   100        b         100        b         4         100        b
               4   100        b         100        b         4         100        b
               5   100        b         np.nan     np.nan    np.nan    100        b
               6   100        b         np.nan     np.nan    np.nan    100        b
               7   np.nan     np.nan    100        b         4         100        b
               8   np.nan     np.nan    100        b         4         100        b
```

I would then manually drop the extra _x and _y columns created during merge...

Is there another/more efficient way of tackling a problem such as this? Feedback much appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I was you I would first manipulate the df_new and to replace the 0s with 100 in your case and then to push the pd.merge, like this :

```
df_new["value"].loc[df_new.value == 0]=100

df_trial = pd.merge(df_old,
                    df_new,
                    how='outer',
                    on=("id", "value", "color")) #<---
```

The result is as expected :

```
   id  value color  size
0   1    100     b   4.0
1   2    100     b   4.0
2   3    100     b   4.0
3   4    100     b   4.0
4   5    100     b   NaN
5   6    100     b   NaN
6   7    100     b   4.0
7   8    100     b   4.0
```

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, the value, color, size could be anything, I standardized those values for the sake of showing the example.